# How can we change Call to actions on a card without making user learning process harder and longer?

Tags: material-design, dashboard, cards

**We are designing a new dashboard for our platform which user request on some service and our providers submit offers for user requests.**
when a request submitted by a user, He should wait until service providers react to request. As you may guessed already, CTA buttons change on providers or user reaction. *for example:* user can edit his request until one offer submitted. but after that edit buttons doesn't do anything.
Here we have 2 solution for this kind of situation:

1. Disable buttons which are disable in this state
2. Remove disabled CTA buttons & replace them with buttons that do things

Take a look at uploaded images for better understanding:[image: State 1 (user requested and before submit any offer by providers]

[image: State 2 (providers submitted an offer on request)]

*users should learn about cards we designed for their requests. changing CTA buttons on every state (which is necessary) is making the learning process harder and harder!*
**What should we do about it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion is generated by changing the buttons in the same state when the action is actually going to a next state.

Instead of changing the CTA buttons in the same state, change the state and title like many UI does, showing the current part of the process in which the user is.

This also helps to show the total number of steps, quite useful information for the user.

[image]

Comment: I think you are right... but naming the states and user flows is challenging for us. We should came up with new idea about state steppers. now we are using material stepper UI element in Vuetify. I think designing a new stepper (specially designed for our dashboard) would solve the problem.